# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can't figure out why this code isn't working. Getting these errors: [image]

My react and reactdom are ^17.0.2. Any input is much appreciated!

Form signup

```js
import React from 'react';
import useForm from './useForm';
import validate from './validateInfo';
import './Form.css';

const FormSignup = ({submitForm}) => {
  const {handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm(submitForm, validate);

  return (
    <div className='form-content-right'>
        <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            
            <h1>Get started with us today! Create your account by filling out the information below.</h1>
            <div className='form-inputs'>
            </div>
            <button className='form-input-btn' type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
            <span className='form-input-login'>
                Already have an account? Login <a href='#'>here</a>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormSignup;
```

Form.js:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import FormSignup from './FormSignup';
import FormSuccess from './FormSuccess';
import './Form.css';

const Form = () => {
  const[isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

  {!isSubmitted ? <FormSignup submitForm={submitForm} /> : <FormSuccess/>}

  function submitForm(){
    setIsSubmitted(true);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className = 'form-container'>
        <span className='close-btn'>x</span>
        <div className='form-content-left'>
          <img src='img/img-2.svg' alt='formimg' className='form-img'/>
        </div>
          {!isSubmitted ? (<FormSignup submitForm={submitForm} />) : (<FormSuccess/>)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

In App.js it just displays Form. Trying to follow this tutorial by BrianDesign https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGFG-yQD7Dw

Comment: i get the same error in my nextjs project. I used  "use client"; and then removed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o problema similar e descobri que isso aconteceu devido essa biblioteca useForm não está baixada no pacote React, tive que baixar uma biblioteca via NPM.

**Basta instalar dessa forma:**
npm install react-hook-form

**Puxando a biblioteca:**
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

*Segue link da biblioteca no npm com algumas instruções:* https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form

Importante também se atentar as tags que está dentro do form, pode ser que o React reclame devido uma má estruturação.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please translate your answer to english so everyone can understand it.